# Create a test file of size 1024 bytes using Java

Tags: java, file, filewriter

I am trying to generate a file of size 1024. The code is given below.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;


public class GenerateFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] array = new byte[1024];
    random.nextBytes(array);

    for(byte i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(bytes[i]);
    }
    try {
       File file = new File("testfile");
       FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file);
       out.write(bytes);
       System.out.println("Done ..........");
       out.close();

    if (file.createNewFile()){
        System.out.println("File is created!");
      }

    else {
        System.out.println("File already exists.");
      }

    }
  catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting. I'm not understanding how I can use a bytes array here. Again, I want the file size to be 1024 bytes.

```
GenerateFile.java:20: error: no suitable method found for write(byte[])
        out.write(bytes);
           ^
method Writer.write(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; byte[] cannot be converted to int)
method Writer.write(char[]) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; byte[] cannot be converted to char[])
method Writer.write(String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; byte[] cannot be converted to String)
method OutputStreamWriter.write(int) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; byte[] cannot be converted to int)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Writers and Reader are designed for writing text not binary.  I suggest you use FileOutputStream for binary.

```
// to fill with random bytes.
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(bytes);
    out.write(bytes);
}
```

Alternatively you could use following assuming each character is turned into one byte.

```
try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file)) {
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    Arrays.fill(chars, '.');
    chars[1023] = '\n';
    out.write(chars);
}
```

Comment: How can I fill it with random numbers instead of '.' ?

Comment: @Y.V use the `Random.nextBytes` as you did in your question.

Comment: @Y.V  by definition, text is not random, so only binary makes sense.

Comment: @Y.V In the first loop, it writes random bytes.  Can you be more specific about what you need?